# How to avoid the message "The app didn't start in the required time." while a debugger is attached?

Tags: debugging, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'd like to debug a Windows Store App, but when I attach a debugger the app is quickly killed and I get the message "The app didn't start in the required time."

How do you debug a running Windows Store App if Windows is going to kill the app as soon as you break in the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line tool [PLMDebug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj680085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is part of the [Debugging Tools for Windows package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#installation_directory), can be used to exempt an app from the Process Lifetime Management (PLM) policies.  When put into debug mode, an app will not be subject to termination and will not be automatically suspended.

Usage:

```
plmdebug /enableDebug <PackageFullName> [OptionalDebuggerCommandLine]
```